# Building a 'Concrete' Ramp, Concrete Mix

Tags: concrete, ramp

I'm trying to build a ramp as shown in the picture below.

It will be above a concrete floor connecting to another concrete floor, so I suppose it doesn't have to be very strong as it will not be load bearing. Using it for trolley and it will not be heavier than 30kg.

Here are however some questions which I need some help with.
The country I'm in doesn't sell any pre-mixed concrete, so I'll have to mix them myself.
Can I use only cement and sand without any gravels? From some googling I guess I will be using a ratio of 1:4. Will it be feasible? Will also be using a wire mesh to prevent cracks.

Would appreciate some tips on making the ramp stay adhered to the floor, most probably I'll be chiseling out the flat surface so it could adhere better.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some issues to consider: 1) steepness of ramp, 2) structural support, 3) design of bottom edge, 4) mix design.

1) In the U.S., we can’t exceed a ratio of 1:12. That is, 1cm of rise requires 12cm of run. Also, it requires a handrail.

2) Concrete weighs about 150 lbs. per cubic foot. Whatever supports the “concrete floor” will also need to support the concrete ramp.

3) Concrete that comes to a point, will “chip off” over time, especially if wheelchairs roll over it. I’d chip down into the concrete floor (if it’s structurally capable) so you have a 4cm or so edge. (We often place a piece of rebar within 3/4” of the edge too.)

4) we like a “rich” mix for tapered concrete projects. That is to say, a 5 sack or more mix is important. Also, do not use too much water. If it’s too runny it will not keep it’s shape on the slope.

There are many factors in the design and finishing. Here’s a site that may help.

https://www.concreteconstruction.net/how-to/materials/top-10-myths-in-concrete-construction_o

Comment: I would round out this good answer with 1:4 ratio will be kind of heavy on the cement for hand mixes I usually use 1:5. , how to anchor the ramp ether chip the surface or drill a few holes and put some metal in them sticking up an inch or 2. I will drill holes just big enough for a nail and put the nail(s) in the hole(s) you can go bigger and use rebar but it will be fine with nails.+

Comment: Based on the original description (trolley, 30kg), I suspect this is not for wheelchairs (where the 1:12 ADA slope applies) but for moving a cart with stuff on it.

Comment: I have used galvanized nails for years especially when patching holes in a slab adding the nails keeps the patch from shifting quite well.